# IDEA - How can I place braces on the next line for .gradle files?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, intellij-2020

In the *Code Style* settings of IntelliJ IDEA, there aren't any subcategories for `.gradle` files (e.g., `build.gradle`), and under *Other File Types*, there isn't any option to modify brace placements. I did not find solutions on to set brace placement for `.gradle` files.

**What I'm trying to do:** Make the braces look like this by default and after reformatting:

```
repositories
{
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Instead of this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Is this change possible using the current version of IntelliJ IDEA? (2020.1.1)

Changing the code style settings for Groovy does not have an effect for some reason.

[image]

Braces for a Groovy class is placed correctly as in the settings. (This is tested in a `.gradle` file.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Settings (Preferences on macOS) → *Editor* → *Code Style* → *Groovy* → *Wrapping and Braces* → *Braces placement* → ***Other** option does not work as expected.

Please vote for the issue [IDEA-241366](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-241366).

Answer (score 1):

`.gradle` files are actually Groovy files. You can check that by looking under *Editor* → *File Types* → *Groovy*.

As such, you can modify the code style for Groovy to move braces onto the next line by going under *Editor* → *Code Style* → *Groovy* → *Wrapping and Braces* tab → *Braces placement* and tweaking it to your liking.

Comment: Upvoted for your effort! But I did try changing the settings in the Groovy section, and it didn't apply to `.gradle` files for some reason...

Comment: Okay, can you confirm that `*.gradle` is a registered pattern under groovy in `Editor` > `File Types`?

Comment: Weird... yes `*.gradle` is included in the Groovy file type. And when I click the `4 spaces` thing on the status bar, it does lead me to the Groovy code style settings. And when I write a class in the `.gradle` file, the braces are placed correctly...

Comment: Yep, so I think it's an Intellij issue. I assume, based on your screenshot, you're not using Linux, so maybe post a comment on the issue Andrey raised saying it's also happening on Linux (or whichever OS you're using)